# I cannot register a specific Hotmail account

Tags: outlook.com

I'm sending an email to let's say `xyz@hotmail.com` and Hotmail returns error email that the email was not delivered to `xyz@hotmail.com` - same as when the account does not exist. So I have tried to register it and it says that I cannot register that account.

Why I cannot register it?

Is there any waiting period?

(Note that the account name that I'm trying to regiter is not something like `mail@hotmail.com` or `admin@hotmail.com`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotmail will not let anyone else register with an existing Windows Live ID username before 365 days after that username has been cancelled/deleted.

It may also be possible that someone has registered a Windows Live ID username *without* opening a hotmail account.  In that case, nobody else can use that Windows Live ID username in a hotmail email-address.